# Using QgsAnnotationLayer()/QgsAnnotationManager() in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Feel like I've been banging my head against the wall here.
I'm writing a plugin. As part of the functionality, I have need to programmatically add a list of annotations to the map.
What I have: list of coordinates (selected using `QgsMapToolEmitPoint`), list of corresponding plaintext notes.

Now, I've been trying to use either `QgsAnnotationLayer` or `QgsAnnotationManager` to create these annotations.

Code for `AnnotationLayer`:

```
    <<in constructor>>
    self.notelayer = QgsAnnotationLayer(name ="Annotations", options = QgsAnnotationLayer.LayerOptions)

    <<inside a method>>

    self.notelayer.clear()
    
    for i in range(len(self.xydata)):
        annotation = QgsAnnotationPointTextItem.create()

        annotation.setText(self.xynotes[i])
        annotation.setPoint(QgsPointXY(self.xydata[i][0],self.xydata[i][1]))

        QgsProject.instance().annotationManager().addAnnotation(annotation)

        self.notelayer.addItem(annotation)
```

`xydata` has the coordinates in float, and `xynotes` has the plaintext.
I was getting an *insufficient arguments error* with this, so I tried using annotation manager instead. That itself had issues.

What I need is a simple example of how to actually use them to make and manage annotations. I couldn't find any examples on the web.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are only missing a couple of things- to pass a `QgsCoordinateTransformContext` object to the `LayerOptions` constructor, and to add the annotation layer to the project.

`QgsAnnotationLayer` inherits from `QgsMapLayer` so you can add it to the project like any other map layer.

Here is a minimal example which you will have to adapt only slightly to implement inside your plugin:

```py
xy_notes = ['Surfing', 'Fishing', 'Camping', 'Skiing', 'Hiking']
xy_data = [(16035000, -4640000), (14668973, -1375954), (12679771, -2523962), (16509000, -4370100), (16914498, -3353025)]

notelayer = QgsAnnotationLayer('Annotations', QgsAnnotationLayer.LayerOptions(QgsProject.instance().transformContext()))

for i in range(len(xy_notes)):
    a = QgsAnnotationPointTextItem(xy_notes[i],
                                    QgsPointXY(xy_data[i][0], xy_data[i][1]))
    a_id = notelayer.addItem(a)
    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(notelayer)
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Simple code examples help so much, thank you.

Comment: No problem, @quagzlor. You're most welcome :-)